# Is there an O(|V|) algorithm for adding a new node to a minimum spanning tree, given the old minimum spanning tree from a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I know that it can be updated in O(|V| + |E|) by using a DFS, but is it possible to update in O(|V|)?

Edit: If this isn't possible, how exactly would an O(|V| + |E|) algorithm work?

Answer (score 1):

Updating Minimum Spanning Tree(MST) of a graph is not limited to connecting the new vertex to the existing MST. It should also be validated that the edges used in the initial MST are still the cheapest possible way to connect all the vertices. In some cases, v<sub>k</sub> may be such a node that it could overhaul the entire existing MST of a graph G. The new vertex and the edges that come along with it may form a cheaper way to connect the vertices of the graph, and consequently, some(or all) edges in the initial MST may become *not the cheapest*.

One such case can be constructed rather easily. Consider the initial graph G=(V={1,2,3}, E={(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)}) in which each edge has the weight of 100. Then introduce a vertex 4, and edges from 4 to each other vertices, each with weight 1. The initial MST of G would have any two of the elements of E, but after the addition of the new node, the MST would be formed by entirely different edges.

Perhaps a clever data structure may yield you a better time complexity than O(|E|), but the need to check the validity(i.e. whether they are still the cheapest way of connecting all the vertices) of each edge of the initial MST as well as the newly added edges implies a time complexity dependent on the size of |E|. It is a valid idea that an initial MST may provide useful information that could help extend it to cover a new vertex with lesser time complexity. However, the definition of MST relies heavily on the graph itself, and updating the graph can possibly *invalidate* all of the initial MST, rendering the information it indicates regarding the graph useless. As a result, although I haven't exactly provided a mathematical proof here, I do not think there is an O(|V|) algorithm to update an MST when a new node(and edges to it) is added to a graph.